# pushViewController vs showDetailViewController

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, adaptive-ui

Should I use `UISplitViewController`'s `showViewController:` & `showDetailViewController:` methods alone to push/present view controllers from iOS 8?

I try to convert my app with adaptive UI. So using splitview controller as a rootviewcontroller. But confused about pushing view controllers.

Thanks

Comment: See this entire video or specifically from this moment: https://youtu.be/o_HukQ-IKH8?list=PLsJq-VuSo2k26duIWzNjXztkZ7VrbppkT&t=2727

Answer (score 1):

You should always use `showDetailViewController` ,when present detailView from masterView.

> In a horizontally regular environment, the split view controller installs vc as the secondary view controller.
>
> In a horizontally compact environment, the split view controller presents vc modally.

Or You can keep use `showDetailViewController`  in all cases and forget about `showViewController`  ,the system will do the choice for you.

Comment: To present a view controller, we can use showDetailViewController: method. That is fine. To push a view controller can we you the same method?